# How to use a batch script to zip files with unique passwords?

Tags: command-line, batch-file, passwords, zip

Good day. I was wondering if there is a way to write a batch script that converts files into password-encrypted zip folders (each zip folder will have a unique password)?

I have seen several tutorials on creating a batch script for zip folders for *one* preset & consistent password, but I was wondering if there is a way to have the batch script refer to a set of randomized passwords recorded in a .csv file to create zip files with distinct passwords?

Comment: Since you mention "batch", are you asking about [tag:windows] [tag:batch-file]s?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a `file.csv` (space-separated filenames):

```
file1 file2 file3,password1,output1
file4 file5,password2,output2
file2 file5,password3,output3
```

You can use the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat file.csv | while IFS="," read -r files password output; do zip -e -P $password $output $files; done
```

Comment: It appears (now) that the OP wants a Windows batch file.  Also, please research the need to quote things in shell scripts, and UUOC.